# CSS icon over image: How can I resize the icon size when resizing the browser

Tags: css

I have some diagram image. I have written some texts and images over it which are generated dynamically. I could resize the text on the image by using the `vm` unites for `font-size`. 
Now I am facing problem to resize the icon for example the one with the image id `switch_icon`. I am using the  the `@media only` but the icon size does not change when resizing the browser.

```
<style type="text/css">

.image_label {
  position: relative;
}
.image_label img {
  display: block;
}
.image_label span {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index:1;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
  background: #ffff80; 

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 300px)  and (max-width: 500px){
    #switch_icon{
        height:40px;
        width:40px;}

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 300px) {
    #switch_icon{
        height:12px;
        width:12px;}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 150px) {
    #switch_icon{
        height:4px;
        width:4px;
}

</style>

<div class="image_label">

   <span style="bottom: 71.5%; left: 49.5%;">12 °C</span>
   <span style="bottom: 62%; left: 49.5%;">15 °C</span>

   <img src="http://test.com/portal/attachment/download?uid=9b8ab620-29a5-4274-ac19-c0b097cef42a" alt="file_schema" width="100%" />
   <span style="bottom: 74%; left: 41%;" ><img id="switch_icon" src="/portal/IconServlet/1970"  /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? I did the tests with FireFox and the icon is correctly resizing with media queries.

Comment: Most likely your browser is bigger than 50-500px. Most devices are 300-1840 pixels. You can use percents for width/height.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your css don't forget to close your media queries. "}"

Comment: Copy this code and put it between your Head Tags in your HTML file. This prints out the width of the screen of your device. `<script> var screenWith = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(screenWith); </script> ` To see the Log open your Web Inspector on a browser and find Console --> Logs